# Abstract class of children

Tags: java

I have A question I have a parent class that is Abstract and the child is not Abstract and Also does not have the override method but the child of the child has it
Java gave an error message to me what can I do with out making the first child abstract and don't add the overriding method?

**This is the parent:**

```
public abstract class MobileDevice {
    public abstract void  display();
} //end class
```

**This is the first child:**

```
public class MobileComputer extends MobileDevice {
    public MobileComputer(String b, double s) {
        super(b,s);
    } //end cons
 } //end class
```

**This is the second child "child of child":**

```
public class TabletComputer extends MobileComputer {
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("");
    }
} //end class
```

Comment: you can´t skip the step of beeing in need to override `display`, but could make `MobileComputer` `abstract` aswell

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three primary options:

1. Make `MobileComputer` abstract, which means you don't need to implement the method in that class
2. Implement the method in `MobileComputer`, but leave it blank, or have it throw an exception such as `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`.
3. Make an interface called `Displayable` (or something) with the `display()` method and only have `TabletComputer` implement it.

Comment: yes I think the interface is what they want, THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

If you are extending any abstract class you have to implement all its abstract methods or declare that class as abstract.
Declare `MobileComputer` as abstract or implement `display()` method (empty method is also acceptable as it will remove at least compilation errors).